# Subgraph with max nodes

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I have the graph with N nodes. I have to create the longest subgraph (with max nodes). One node can be connected with `only 2` nodes. So which nodes should I take to create this `(max)` subgraph?

What I'm doing is:
1: From initial node. I start `2` DFS functions. (from anothers nodes only `1`).

2: For some node in DFS I use `F()` function to check all neighbours and find maximum way that I have to go. Then I'm saving the index of the node in which I have to go in `index` variable and starting DFS from `index`.

The problem is that this algorithm is too slow. How can I optimize it? Maybe there is `special` algorithm to find `maximum subgraph`?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int used[20];
int m[20][20];
int c;


int F(int v) {
    used[v] = 1;

    int maxn = 0, index = -1, t;

    for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
        if(!used[i] && m[v][i] == 1) {
            t = F(i);

            if(t > maxn) {
                maxn = t;
                index = i;
            }
        }
    }

    if(index != -1) {
        used[v] = 0;
        return maxn + 1;
    }
    else {
        used[v] = 0;
        return 1;
    }

}

int DFS(int v) {
    used[v] = 1;
    int maxn = 0, index = -1, t;
    for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
        if(!used[i] && m[v][i] == 1) {
            t = F(i);
            if(t > maxn) {
                maxn = t;
                index = i;
            }
        }
    }

    if(index != -1) {
        return DFS(index) + 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {

        cin >> c;

        for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; ++ j)
                cin >> m[i][j];
        }

        int maxn = DFS(0) + DFS(0) + 1;
        cout << maxn << endl;

}
```

Comment: a few questions: 1) is the graph acyclic? 2) why do you start the DFS twice `int maxn = DFS(0) + DFS(0) + 1;`? shouldn't this function return twice the same?

Comment: @bro 1: It doesnt matter. 2: Like I said `1` node can be connected with `2` nodes. So initially I start from `0` node, find necessary neighbour. Then this neighbour can be connected with one node, because it's already connected with parent. 3: No, because the best necessary node will be marked as `used` So I have to use second best node.

Comment: What you're looking for is a [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path). Sounds NP-Complete to me.

Comment: @beaker Hamiltonian Path has all nodes or not? There can be the situation that my last node is not connected with first node.

Comment: @beaker Also can you give some more information, please?

Comment: A Hamiltonian Path on an unknown (maximum) subset of vertices is just as hard as a Hamiltonian Path on all vertices.

Comment: @James: bro's original question #1 *does* matter, because if the graph is acyclic you can solve the problem *exponentially* faster.  And as beaker points out, this problem is at least as hard as the NP-complete Hamiltonian Path problem, because any program that solves your problem automatically solves the HP problem too: a HP exists if and only if the longest path it returns contains every vertex.

Comment: @j_random_hacker No, I mean that I don't know if the graph acyclic or not. Because there can be acyclic or cyclic graph.

Comment: @RasulKerimov "One node can be connected with only 2 nodes." Does this mean every node is connected to exactly 2 nodes?